# Find the durations and their maximum between the dataset in an interval in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

This is related to my older question [Find the durations and their maximum between the dataset in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889328/find-the-durations-and-their-maximum-between-the-dataset-in-shell-script)

I have a dataset as:

```
ifile.txt
2
3
2
3
2
20
2
0
2
0
0
2
1
2
5
6
7
0
3
0
3
4
5
```

I would like to find out different duration and their maximum between the 0 values in 6 values interval.

My desire output is:

```
ofile.txt
6 20
1 2
1 2
1 2
5 7
1 3
3 5
```

Where

```
6 is the number of counts until next 0 within 6 values (i.e. 2,3,2,3,2,20) and 20 is the maximum value among them;
1 is the number of counts until next 0 within next 6 values (i.e. 2,0,2,0,0,2) and 2 is the maxmimum;
Next 1 and 2 are withing same 6 values;
5 is the number of counts until next 0 within next 6 values (i.e. 1,2,5,6,7,0) and 7 is the maximum among them;
And so on
```

As per the answer in my previous question, I was trying with this:

```
awk '(NR%6)==0
$0!=0{
  count++
  max=max>$0?max:$0
}
$0==0{
  if(count){
      print count,max
  }
  count=max=""
}
END{
  if(count){
      print count,max
  }
}
'  ifile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A format command added to the ***EDIT2*** solution given by RavinderSingh13 which will print exact desire output:

```
awk '
$0!=0{
  count++
  max=max>$0?max:$0
  found=""
}
$0==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  next
}
FNR%6==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  found=1
}
END{
  if(!found){
      print count,max
  }
}
'  Input_file | awk '!/^ /' | awk '$1 != 0'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
6 20
1 2
1 2
1 2
5 7
1 3
3 5
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** Adding another solution which will print values in every 6 elements along with zeros coming in between.

```
awk '
$0!=0{
  count++
  max=max>$0?max:$0
  found=""
}
$0==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  next
}
FNR%6==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  found=1
}
END{
  if(!found){
      print count,max
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
6 20
1 2
1 2
0 0
1 2
5 7
1 3
3 5
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment OP doesn't want to reset of count of non-zeros when a zero value comes in that case try following.

```
awk '
$0!=0{
  count++
  max=max>$0?max:$0
  found=""
}
FNR%6==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  found=1
}
END{
  if(!found){
      print count,max
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
6 20
3 2
5 7
.......
```

---

---

Could you please try following(written and tested with posted samples only).

```
awk '
$0!=0{
  count++
  max=max>$0?max:$0
  found=""
}
$0==0{
  count=FNR%6==0?count:0
  found=""
}
FNR%6==0{
  print count,max
  count=max=0
  found=1
}
END{
  if(!found){
      print count,max
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Would it be possible to suggest how to find the average. Here I have my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621874/find-the-durations-and-their-average-between-the-dataset-in-an-interval-in-shell